# Recorder Working for first time then it records only for 3 seconds

Tags: java, android

In this code whenever i install the app first it works properly but when i used it repeatedly to record the calls it does not work properly it only records the audio for 3 seconds.So i would like to know what is the mistake i have done.Please let me know if anything is wrong.The audio is being recorded properly but after that the audio file has only 3 seconds of audio.

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static boolean status;
    MediaRecorder media;

    private void startrecorder(boolean status) {
       if(status) {
           media = new MediaRecorder();
           String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/"
                   + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "record.3gp";
           media.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
           media.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
           media.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
           media.setOutputFile(path);
           try {
               media.prepare();
               media.start();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
       else{
           media.stop();

       }
    }



    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String phoneNumber){

        if(lastState == state){
//No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Number inside onCallStateChange : "  + phoneNumber);
        
        switch(state){
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                startrecorder(true);

                Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming Call Ringing " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

                if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    isIncoming = false;
                    startrecorder(true);
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing Call Started " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
//Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                startrecorder(false);
                if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
//Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing but no pickup" + phoneNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime +" Date " + new Date() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(isIncoming){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming " + phoneNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else{

                    Toast.makeText(context, "outgoing " + phoneNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime +" Date " + new Date() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For video there's usually an array of blobs, not sure how this implementation differs since I see no array.
Try using `media.start(100);`, it might work.

Comment: I am trying to record the audio

Comment: I understand; `MediaRecorder` is pretty much the same for audio and video. Look for video recording implementations, and adapt it to audio. That being said, from personal experience, this has been fickle for me too, and was a pain to get it to work, rewrote my code multiple times since I couldn't pinpoint the issue. All the best! Post your solution here once you solve it.